# Java Map Matching Key

Tags: java, dictionary

i am facing a problem which is: 
I have map containing string and string. When i print that map i can see that there is a key 
"0-8166-3835-7". But when i am trying to get it, there is nothing to get returned, like no matching found...
My code:

```
    //Open a stream to read from file with isbn's AND titles
    Scanner IsbnTitle = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/Proskopos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ReadUrl/IsbnTitle.txt"));

    //Create a Map to save both ISBN's and Titles
    Map <String,String> IsbnTitleMap = new HashMap();

    while(IsbnTitle.hasNext()){
        String recordIsbnTitle = IsbnTitle.nextLine();
        UrlFunctions.AddToMap(Recognised , recordIsbnTitle, IsbnTitleMap);
    }
.....
.....
        Set IsbnSet = new HashSet();
    while (IsbnFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String isbn = IsbnFile.nextLine();
        IsbnSet.add(isbn);
    }

    //Create an Iterator for IsbnSet
    Iterator IsbnIt =IsbnSet.iterator();

String suffix = IsbnIt.next().toString();

    String OPACIALtitle = UrlFunctions.GetOpacTitle(suffix, IsbnTitleMap);
```

The code above is the only part in main about MAP and below are the functions i call:

```
    static String GetOpacTitle(String opIsbn, Map IsbnTitle) {
    String OpacTitle = null;
    String isbn = opIsbn;
    Map isbnMap = IsbnTitle;
    System.out.println(isbn);
    if ( isbnMap.containsKey(isbn)){
        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    }
    //String tade = isbnMap.get(isbn).toString();
    //System.out.println("*************" + tade);

    return OpacTitle;
}


    static void AddToMap(int Recognise, String recordIsbnfollowed, Map IsbnfollowedMap) {

    Map isbnsth = IsbnfollowedMap;
    String records = recordIsbnfollowed;
    int recs= Recognise;


    if (recs == 0 || recs == 3) {
    String isbn = records.substring(0, 10);
    String title = records.substring(10);
    isbnsth.put(isbn, title);
//        System.out.println(isbn);
        }else if (recs == 1) {
            String isbn = records.substring(0, 14);
            String title = records.substring(14);
            isbnsth.put(isbn, title);
//            System.out.println(isbn);
        }
    }
```

I cant understand where the problem is.. Maybe it is something like encoding of the suffix cames from a set, and the key from a map? they are both string.. dont think so..!!!
So? Can you help?

EDIT: I am trully sorry if you find the code difficult to read :\ I will follow your advices!!
BUT in case that anyone else has the same problem the solution was what Brand said below.. (I re-post it)

> You probably have some whitespace in the Strings that you are reading form the file and storing in the Map. If this is the case use String.trim() before storing the value in the Map, and also before querying for the same string. – Brad 3 hours ago

Thank you all

Comment: Your code doesn't show where IsbnFile comes from... your code would also be a lot easier to read if you'd follow normal Java naming conventions...

Comment: As Jon says: write your variables with lower case so tehy don't get wrongly coded :-/ very confusing to read. Same for method names, they should be lowercase. You can indeed have a problem with encodings. Make sure your keys are created in a similar way (not reading one from UTF-8 and the other one from a windows encoded file).

Comment: You probably have some whitespace in the Strings that you are reading form the file and storing in the Map. If this is the case use String.trim() before storing the value in the Map, and also before querying for the same string.

Comment: show the code which prints the map and you see the key.

Comment: When printing your keys, it's probably helpful to surround them with quotes (or some other character) so you can see if there's any whitespace that's included that you haven't noticed.

Comment: I don't think the problem is encoding, as at least the example has only ASCII characters. I would assume a whitespace problem as well.

Comment: Test if the value associated to the key "0-8166-3835-7" is null or not. If it is not, then you have added an empty string there, or a string with white spaces (tab, enter, normal space, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to my comment that identified the problem. When comparing Keys in a Map you must be very careful about white space and case sensitivity. These types of issues commonly occure when reading data from Files because it's not always obvious what characters are being read. Even looking in your debugger whitepsace cna be an issue.

Always try to "normalize" your data by trimming leading and trailing whitespace before storing it in a Map.